# CSS add shadow/border to individual bootstrap button when active

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am creating a frontend in the react framework and using bootstrap 5.3 for designing.

For my understanding shadows are deactivated in bootstrap as a standard, now. So buttons do not show this shadow/border if the button is active as shown in the bootstrap v5.0 documentation.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/

Unfortunately I do not understand how to customize individual buttons direct in the code. It is possible to add an style tag to the button, or in grouped buttons a label tag to activate this shadow for individual buttons?

```
style={{*here some CSS magic*}}
```

Here some sample code for three buttons I want to customize with this kind of shadow we know from v5.0.

```
<div className="row">
  <h4>Choose buffer</h4>
</div>
<div className="row">
  <div className="col-sm-4 p-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <input type="radio" className="btn-check" name="chooseBuffer" id="buffer1" autoComplete="off" onClick={() => measurementConfig.buffer = 1 } />
    <label className="btn btn-lg btn-warning" htmlFor="buffer1"><span className="bi-database-add"></span>&nbsp;Buffer 1</label>
  </div>
  <div className="col-sm-4 p-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <input type="radio" className="btn-check" name="chooseBuffer" id="buffer2" autoComplete="off" onClick={() => measurementConfig.buffer = 2 } />
    <label className="btn btn-lg btn-success" htmlFor="buffer2"><span className="bi-database-add"></span>&nbsp;Buffer 2</label>
  </div>
  <div className="col-sm-4 p-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <input type="radio" className="btn-check" name="chooseBuffer" id="buffer3" autoComplete="off" onClick={() => measurementConfig.buffer = 3 } />
    <label className="btn btn-lg btn-info" htmlFor="buffer3"><span className="bi-database-add"></span>&nbsp;Buffer 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a boolean state and based on the condition display your CSS for the buttons

Answer (score 0):

use this css, it will target the next adjacent label of the checked radio input.

```
input[type="radio"]:checked+label.btn {
   border: 1px solid #000; //add border/shadow here
}
```